# "TypeError: _axios.default.get is not a function"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I try to write mock test using jest and @vue/test-utils,
Here is the "**bots.spec.js**" / test file.

```
jest.mock('axios', ()=>({
  getBots: () => {
    const result = {
      __esModule: true,
      
      data: () => ({
        name: "demo",
        _id: "62e8d832afdaad001b65bff5",
      })
    }
    return Promise.resolve(result)
  }
}))

let getBots;
describe('Load bots function', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()

    getBots = (await import('../../src/services')).default
  })

  it('Should load given bots', async() =>{
    const bot_Name = "demo"
    const bot_id = "62e8d832afdaad001b65bff5"

    const actual = await getBots(bot_id)
    expect(actual).toMatch(bot_Name)
  })
})
```

Following error occurred

```
TypeError: _axios.default.get is not a function
```

[screenshot of the occurred error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr25l.png)

Comment: Your test doubles have to match the interface of the thing they're replacing. In this case you seem to have mocked out Axios and replaced it with something that has the interface of what you're supposed to be _testing_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is work for me

```
  jest.mock('axios', ()=>({
  get: () => {
    const result = {
      data:{
        name: "demo",
        _id: "62e8d832afdaad001b65bff5",
      }
    }
    return Promise.resolve(result)
  }
}))

let getBots;
describe('Load bots function', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
    getBots = (await (await import('../../src/services')).getBots)
  })

  it('Should load given bots', async() =>{
    const expectedResponse = {
      name: "demo",
      _id: "62e8d832afdaad001b65bff5",

    }
    const actual = await getBots()

    expect(actual.data).toStrictEqual(expectedResponse)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can mock like this and choose value returned later

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(),
}));
```

The return value can be set like this

```
it('Should load given bots', async() =>{
  (mockAxios.get as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      data: {
        name: "demo",
        _id: "62e8d832afdaad001b65bff5",
      }
    })
  );
  const bot_Name = "demo"
  const bot_id = "62e8d832afdaad001b65bff5"

  const actual = await getBots(bot_id)
  expect(actual).toMatch(bot_Name)
})
```